# Query selector is null when trying to use a value from an HTML file on another

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am doing an interactive rating page like [this one](https://lucashdoa.github.io/interactive-rating-component/) but when I'm trying to print the rate selected in the second file it is not printing and displaying an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: rates is null

Here's my index.html file code:

```
    <div class="rating-container">
            <div class="rating">1</div>
            <div class="rating">2</div>
            <div class="rating">3</div>
            <div class="rating">4</div>
            <div class="rating">5</div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="button-container">
            <button class="submit-btn" onClick="checked()">
              SUBMIT
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
```

My checked.html code:

```
<div id="rating-selected">
      <p>you selected <span class="rated"></span> out of 5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="title-container">
```

My app.js code:

```
let ratings=document.getElementsByClassName('rating');
const quali=document.getElementsByClassName('rated');
const rates=document.querySelector('.rating-container'); //Div que tiene los ratings
const rating=document.getElementsByClassName('rating');
let rate=0;

for (var i=0; i<rating.length; i++){
  rating[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}

  rates.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    
    rate=event.target.innerHTML;
        //console.log(rate);
  });


function checked(){
  window.location.href="checked.html";
  quali.textContent=rate;
  console.log(rate);
}
```

Comment: Once you set `location.href`, your code is no longer running (or it may for a brief period). The new page is running and the code on the other page is gone - unloaded and forgotten by the browser.

Comment: you either need to use localStorage to access your variables at another page or need server-sided scripting such as Java, PHP or Node.js